# Calculating to more decimal places

Tags: calculus

Unfortunately, I have a calculator which can only calculate to up to $x$ decimal places. Let $x = 10$ (like my calculator). My calculator can do $\sqrt 2$, but it comes up with $1.4142135624$. Nowhere *near* the amount of decimal places I would have liked to calculate. I understand that $$\sqrt 2 = 1+\frac{1}{2+\frac{1}{2+\frac{1}{2+\frac{1}{2+\frac{1}{2+\frac{1}{2+\frac{1}{2+\frac{1}{2+}}}}}}}} 
 etc.$$

So, bearing that in mind, can I calculate decimal places from $ax$ th digit to the $(a+1)x$ th digit? Is there an algorithm?

For example, $\frac{1}{7} = 0.\overline{142857}$, and a calculator with $x = 5$ digits would calculate (for $a$ ascending from $0$) $0.1428, 57142, 85714, 28571 $ etc.

How to I do this?

Specifications (very loose):

- a computer programme
- OR an algorithm
- Or a formula (probably not)

**Edit:** I am talking about calculating for *every* single operator out there. I am not just going for $\sqrt {}$, +, - $\times$ or $\div$

Comment: There is no easy method to get, lets say $40$ digits of $\sqrt{2}$, only using a calculator with $10$ digits accuracy. You will have to use a computer software (my suggestion PARI/GP) , if you want so many digits.

Comment: PARI/GP is free, easy to implement, powerful and easy to program, the perfect program for high-precision-calculations. An alternative would be Dario Alperns super calculator (just google alpertron).

Comment: Have you tried googling for answers? Wikipedia has an article on computing square roots that lists about 10 different methods, starting w Newton's method. It includes continued fraction expansion.

Comment: $\sqrt 2 =\color{red}{1+} \frac{1}{2+\frac{1}{2+\frac{1}{2+\frac{1}{2+\frac{1}{2+\frac{1}{2+\frac{1}{2+\frac{1}{2+}}}}}}}} $
 etc.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know whether a program like this can be made or not (I even do not know $p$ of programming), but here is my idea.

Let us consider the example of $\dfrac 17$, when you calculated first time you got

> $$ \frac 17 = 0.14285$$

Now here is the trick, your next calculation should be :

> $$\Big(\frac17-0.14285\Big) \times 100,000=0.71428 $$

From these $2$ results, you can calculate the value of $\dfrac 17$ upto $10$ digits, precisely :

> $$\frac17= 0.1428571428$$

Hope this works!Let me know whether this cannot be done or not.

Comment: What about for irrational numbers?

Comment: Probably you can use binomial theorem for any index : http://gradestack.com/JEE-Main-2015-Complete/Binomial-Theorem/Binomial-Theorem-for-Any/19662-4056-42813-study-wtw